# Format data data coming from MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

```
const Fornecedor = require("../model/Fornecedor")
const Aluguel = require("../model/Aluguel")

router.get('/admin/rent',(req,res)=\>{
Aluguel.findAll().then((alugueis)=\>{
res.render("aluguel/index", {alugueis: alugueis})
```

Como faço para formatar a data, para que apareça: DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ or translate to english, please.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date